# СУБД и база(ы) данных это разные вещи?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, терминология

> Система управления базами данных (СУБД) – это совокупность языковых и
>   программных средств, предназначенных для создания, ведения и
>   совместного использования БД многими пользователями.
>
> Ба́за да́нных — представленная в объективной форме совокупность
>   самостоятельных материалов (статей, расчётов, нормативных актов,
>   судебных решений и иных подобных материалов), систематизированных
>   таким образом, чтобы эти материалы могли быть найдены и обработаны с
>   помощью электронной вычислительной машины (ЭВМ).

Как-то на собесе: Какие базы данных вы использовали?
Начал называть СУБДшки (MySql, PostgreSql). А потом он начал: Что такое СУБД? Что такое база данных?

> Простыми словами я понимаю что база данных это место где хранятся
>   какие-то данные, а СУБД это управление базами данных. То есть СУБД
>   может быть 1, а баз данных много.
>   В моём понимании это 2 разные вещи. Проясните ситуацию.

Comment: https://timeweb.com/media/default/0001/01/781x120xc31c3391c7f6992390982fa4972bf97047e731e8.png.pagespeed.ic.gj7cF2f8mN.png

Comment: Лучше бы собеседующий что путное спросил.

Comment: @TotalPusher я имею ввиду если дойти до самой сути, как будет правильней одно и тоже или разные вещи, я воспринимаю что это разные вещи, а разраб на собесе считает что это одно и тоже, я вот хочу понять

Comment: @TotalPusher я знаю как происходит работа

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Как-то на собеседовании: Какие базы данных вы использовали?

Вопрос очень хороший, но Вы так и не дали на него ответ. (Судя по Вашему сообщению).

Начнем с того **какие базы данных существуют**?

Вообще-то разновидностей много, примерно полсотни. Базы классифицируются по среде хранения (что на каких носителях располагается), по месту хранения (распределённая или централизованная), по содержимому (научная, мультимедийная, историческая), по структурной модели...

*(Все перечислять не буду, конечно же, возьму самые основные, которые чаще всего использовал на практике)*.

1. **Реляционная база данных** называется так от английского «relation», то
   бишь, «отношение». Имеется ввиду математическое понятие, которое для
   удобства нередко заменяют термином «таблица». Если изобразить
   структуру организации хранения данных графически, то схема
   действительно будет напоминать таблицу с ячейками. (Часто
   используемая база данных на практике).
2. **Иерархическая база данных** по своей сути напоминает файловую систему
   в компьютере. Такая же древовидная структура с «корнем» и
   разветвлениями, разными уровнями иерархии. Поэтому файловые системы
   нередко относят к данной разновидности баз.
3. **Объектно-ориентированные базы данных** представляют хранимую в них
   информацию в виде... да, правильно, объектов! А ещё их методов,
   классов и атрибутов. У каждого такого объекта есть собственный
   уникальный идентификатор, так что управляющий софт, написанный на
   каком-нибудь популярном языке программирования, найдёт нужное
   безошибочно.

*Какая из моделей используется, зависит от конкретных задач. Нередко наиболее продуктивными оказываются гибридные решения, объектно-реляционные (Oracle Database, PostgreSQL).*

Всё, что Вы подметили про СУБД(Система управления базы данных) - верно.

Главная функция СУБД – это управление данными (которые могут быть как во внешней, так и в оперативной памяти). СУБД обязательно поддерживает языки баз данных, а также отвечает за копирование и восстановление данных после каких-либо сбоев.

Ответ можно разнести на 30 страниц, если не больше, но подведем некий итог:

> СУБД и база(ы) данных это разные вещи?

**Несомненно - да.**

Система управления базами данных(СУБД) является **субъектом управления** и **программой**, а база данных  **объектом управления** и собственно **данными**, которыми управляет СУБД. Из этого объяснения становится понятно, чем отчается СУБД от БД.

Comment: я работал с mySQL, postgresql, но я сказал, что я работал в СУБД где работал с базами данных

Comment: подошел второй разработчик, спросил у него, он сказал мол это одно и тоже :/, но я так не считаю

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван возможно, не стоит устраиваться в компанию, в которой соискателей собеседует человек считающий СУБД и БД одним и тем же.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, да, на самом деле на практике это считается нормой, частенько слышу от всяких администраторов: "Я работаю с БД MySQL" и это считается нормой... у них, по крайнер мере.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev после того, как я сказал что это разные вещи и рассказал что одно и что другое, мне сказали так: Разные-то да, но в отрыве одного от другого их использовать не получится. Попробуй использовать БД Postgres без работы с СУБД Postgres.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev тогда надо было собеседователю правильно сказать, что это разные вещи, но в отрыве одного от другого их использовать не получится, так правильней?

Comment: *в отрыве одного от другого их использовать не получится* Это в общем случае ошибочное утверждение. Программные средства имеют полное право самостоятельно работать со структурами данных в файловом хранилище, изображая из себя СУБД.

Comment: @Akina Какие программные средства например? Я просто хотел бы почитать и посмотреть про них

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван embedded любого толка - от родных до самописных.

Comment: Вопрос очень плохой. Спросили про базы данных, а не про разновидности баз данных

Comment: @andreymal правильно прочитайте, вы вообще о чем?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван копирую через Ctrl+C прямо из текста вопроса: **«Какие базы данных вы использовали?»** — ни слова про **разновидности**. Вот о чём.

Comment: @andreymal, про разновидность написал потому что человек не знал что отвечать на этот вопрос, вместо того, чтобы назвать разновидности используемых им БД он начал перечислять СУБД.

Comment: @meine ещё раз: вопрос был задан не про разновидности. К вам никаких претензий, но вопрос этот точно не хороший, как вы утверждаете в ответе

Answer (score 4):

Конечно же разные. Кратко:

БД - это данные хранимые в структурированном виде. Обычно в виде набора файлов.

СУБД - это программа или библиотека, которая умеет с этими файлами работать.

Comment: Уже 2 собеседователей разработчиков с кем общался начинали говорить с какими базами данных работали? Я говорю я работал с СУБД в которых и находились базы данных. Они имеют ввиду с какими базами данных работали это с какими СУБД, но СУБД это не база данных, почему те же Middle/Senior разработчики так ошибаются?)

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван потому что так говорить короче, вот и всё. Это не ошибка, это намеренное упущение ненужных деталей.