# База данных и СУБД и их различия

Tags: sql, база-данных

На собеседовании столкнулся с разработчиком и вот диалог:
1) С какими базами данных вы работали: MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL?
   - Я работал с реляционной базой данных, а вы перечислили СУБД.
В итоге я оказался не прав как он говорит и он лил воду водяную, но т.к я новичок я не стал спорить потому что 100% не был уверен, вообще в программировании у меня часто так что я не уверен на 100% хотя знаю допустим как работает то или иное, поэтому не спорил.

В википедии столкнулся с такой фразой:

> Многие специалисты указывают на распространённую ошибку, состоящую в
>   некорректном использовании термина «база данных» вместо термина
>   «система управления базами данных», и указывают на необходимость
>   различения этих понятий.

Не посчитайте меня за глупового, но я не могу разобраться в этой фразе, написано как я понял,  что разработчики путают СУБД и базу данных, поэтому и на СУБД говорят база данных? Аля с базой данных PostgreSQL я работал (хотя это СУБД), об этом там говорится, а то я не очень понял если честно.

Comment: Поздравляю, вы столкнулись с интервьюером, который не захотел признавать допущенную им ошибку. Это частое явление, к сожалению.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev получается когда говорят, я работал с базами данных PostgreSQL, MS SQL, MySQL это неправильно и правильно говорить, я работал с СУБД: PostgreSQL, MS SQL, MySQL, да?

Comment: Д‌‌​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌а.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо большое!

Comment: Просто отвечать надо не так на подобные вопросы. Надо в развернутой форме объяснить человеку почему вы считаете то или другое не той вещью, которой он её называет. С "дураками" спорить бессмысленно - задавят опытом.

Comment: Хочу просто заметить, что большинство людей при общении действительно говорят "база данных" вместо "СУБД" и не различают эти понятия. Хоть это неправильно, но имейте ввиду, что возможно это не первый ваш собеседователь/коллега/знакомый, который будет допускать подобные вольности в формулировках.

Comment: Я бы даже больше сказал. Почти все мои знакомые не различают понятия БД и СУБД. И формально, вы бесспорно правы. Но придется признать, что раз уж большинство не разделают СУБД и БД, то ваш ответ со стороны выглядит как попытка подколоть собеседующего. Из контекста можно понять, какой вопрос задавали и наверное стоит на него и отвечать. В общем то я на вашей стороне, но какой в этом толк, если это мешает на собеседовании?

Comment: Дежавю... Был же такой вопрос недавно?

Comment: [СУБД и база(ы) данных это разные вещи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929894/184217)